# Power BI - couldn't access the data source while sharing the report to people from other organization

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I shared a report to a person from other organization but the user is getting this error message

> couldn't access the data source

I granted "Viewer" permission at the report level and dataset level, but when I want to grant viewer permission at the workspace level, I am getting the message:

> One or more email addresses with the following domains are outside
> your organization

What/Where should be done in order to grant the permission at the workspace level? Who should I talk to: Power BI admin? AD admin?

Answer (score 1):

Check setting in Admin Portal:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this Power BI related? I am asking as I am not admin at Power BI level...

Comment: Yes, this is related. Admin can go to [...] -> Settings -> Admin portal;

Comment: Thanks mate. I don't have access to Tenant settings, but I think this is the answer!!

Comment: I  have already enabled  it but I am still unable to add emails other than my organization